# Problemas de configuración - redirección de subdominio con Hostinger para cloud hosting

Tags: hosting, redirección, configuración

Recién contrate un cloud hosting con la empresa de hostinguer, anteriormente realice la compra de un dominio separado que ya migre con ellos, cree un subdominio pero a la hora de configurar mi cloud hosting me pide insertar un dominio, el cuál ya no es válido porque ya tengo registrado en otro hosting, de esta misma forma no puedo utilizar un subdominio? si es así cómo se lograría o que pasos se deben seguir para redirigir de mi hosting con dominio a ese cloud hosting pero con un subdominio, ejemplo patito.com es mi hosting principal y quiero que feo.patito.com me redirija a ese cloud hosting.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu dominio principal (patito.com) debes buscar el administrador de dominios, luego identifica el editor de zonas. Una vez dentro debes agregar un registro **tipo A**, te pedirá un nombre, que en tu caso seria feo.patito.com y una direccion IP que es la ubicación real de tu subdominio (puede ser en el mismo servidor principal o uno diferente)
[image: Ejemplode Sub dominio]

Comment: Muchas gracias :D